# Silverlight passing parameters between pages using HyperlinkButton

Tags: silverlight, parameters, hyperlink

I have a page that displays a list of users. each user has an ID and a HyperlinkButton to watch more details about the user.

When pressing the HyperlinkButton, I would like to navigate to another page (called UserDetails) and somehow read the ID of the user that was pressed.

How can I do that?

Thanks,
   Ronny

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I Found a nice solution, but I would like to hear something that is more elegant.

Within the UriMapper section I have added another UriMapping:

```
<uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/UserDetails/{UserId}" MappedUri=/Views/UserDetails.xaml"/>
```

By doing so, all navigation in the format of "/UserDetails/XXX will be navigated to same page, UserDetails.xaml.

So now my HyperlinkButton is generated with a NavigateUri with the needed format:

NavigateUri="/UserDetails/1234"

Now, on the UserDetails.xaml page, in the OnNavigatedTo method, I can parse the Uri parameter (e.Uri) and load the User details accordingly.

Comment: No need to parse the Uri. Change the MappedUri to "/Views/UserDetails.aspx?id={UserId}" next you'll be able to use NavigationContext.QueryString["id"] to get the value

Answer (score 6):

you can use NavigationContext to get data from query string.. try this:

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="/UserDetails?userId=123" />
```

and than in the navigated page something like this

```
string customerId = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["customerid"];
```

Answer (score 2):

What about put `ID` in query string like so.

```
<HyperlinkButton 
  x:Name="btn" /**other properties**/
  NavigateUri="http://www.yoururl.com/details.aspx?ID=1234">
</HyperlinkButton>
```

in `Details.aspx` you can put ID in `initParams` property of silverlight object

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
  <param name="initParams" value='<%= GetID() %>' />
</object>
```

in `Details.aspx.cs` , code behind of `Details.aspx`, you fill the initParams like so

```
public string GetID(){
   return string.Format("ID={0}", Request.QueryString[0]);
}
```

then, you can read the ID from your silverlight application startup

```
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
       int ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.InitParams["ID"]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay.
But is it possible to stay in the same aspx file?
And use the relative path such as "NavigateUri="/UserDetails" + the ID

Comment: Of course it is possible. But why do you need to navigate and pass data to the same page if you can pass the data without navigating? can't you?

Comment: I do need to navigate between the two pages, the first is the page and that shows the list of the users (UsersList.xaml) and the second is the one that shows a specific user details (UserDetails.xaml).

I Found a nice solution, but I would like to hear something that is more elegant solution.