# Pass values between page navigation

Tags: c#, silverlight, navigation

I have an autogenerated `DataGrid`, which gets populated after calling a service that binds it to the results from the SQL server. I have a `Hyperlink` button on the rows too to navigate to a new page `Details.xaml`. I want to know how can I pass the values of different columns like `pkProductID`,`productName` of my grid to a new page `Details.xaml`?

**DataGrid on my Home.xaml page**

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="163" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380" Margin="10,59,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="ProductGrid"  Visibility="Collapsed">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Hyperlink">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="gridTemplate">

                         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center"  >
                        <HyperlinkButton Content="Hyperlinkbutton" Tag="Hyperlinkbutton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" NavigateUri="/Details" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

**Edited- Here is Home.xaml.cs that contains the result of rows returned. I have used linq to Sql classes (sharing becuase I thought this might help)**

```
public void webService_GetProductsCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetProductsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
 ProductGrid.ItemsSource = e.Result;           
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silverlight passing parameters between pages using HyperlinkButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692553/silverlight-passing-parameters-between-pages-using-hyperlinkbutton)

Comment: @VadimMartynov Went throught the above link, still can't figure out how to send my column values in a query string? they have hard coded. Can you help?